# JMS Specification: QueueRequestor and TopicRequestor are not interfaces

Tags: junit, jms, easymock

Can anyone explain why in the JMS spec (both 1.1 and 2.0) `javax.jms.QueueRequestor` and `javax.jms.TopicRequestor` are a classes and not interfaces?

Almost all of types (connections, sessions, destinations, messages etc.) in the JMS spec are interfaces which makes sense for me since the spec only defines a generic interface and let the JMS providers implement the instantiations.
Only the Exceptions are classes (which also makes sense for me) to simplify implementations.

But *only* `javax.jms.QueueRequestor` and `javax.jms.TopicRequestor` doesn't follow this convention. This makes it more complicated to mock it in unit tests.

Does anyone know the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I already know the answer now:
These two classes are just a simple default implementation to cover basic request/reply scenario using the other required interfaces (TopicRequestor e.g. uses  TopicSession, Topic and  TemporaryTopic) without knowing anything about their specific implementation.

So they are just an abbreviation to simplify the realization of the request/reply scenario (for JMS clients). So it is not necessary for JMS providers to implement their own version of these patterns.

Sorry for posting this question too early.